azure unity Catalog and Hive Metastore objects are not supported in Unity Catalog
I am trying to create a views in my unity catalog but unable to create the views and getting error as below like, also, I have two compute which is one enabled unity catalog with shared resource and another one which is SQL warehouse compute both i tried use but no luck.
sample query
  create view catalogname.catalogshcema.viewname as
    select * from hive_metastore.data_vault.tablename

`AnalysisException: [UC_COMMAND_NOT_SUPPORTED.WITHOUT_RECOMMENDATION] The command(s): Creating a persistent view that references both Unity Catalog and Hive Metastore objects are not supported in Unity Catalog.` 

Kindly assist

This is expected behavior. In the Unity Catalog world, within UC, a view can be created from tables and other views in multiple schemas and catalogs.
However, you cannot create a view in UC referencing the Hive Metastore or vice versa.

A view is a read-only object created from one or more tables and views within a metastore. It exists in the third layer of the Unity Catalog's three-level namespace. You can create a view using tables and other views across different schemas and catalogs.
Dynamic views offer the ability to enforce row- and column-level access control, along with providing data masking capabilities.
Know more about Dynamic views
Code/syntax:
CREATE VIEW <catalog-name>.<schema-name>.<view-name> AS
SELECT <query>;

I have tried the approach below:
CREATE VIEW spark_catalog.default.experienced_employee
  (id COMMENT 'Unique identification number', Name)
  COMMENT 'View for experienced employees'
AS SELECT id, name
   FROM all_employee

Results:

